# Global dynamic arraylist not update/modify in function while getting volley response in JSON format from google place search API

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, android-volley

lat and long are variables having current location

```
if(lat!=0.0||longg!=0.0){
search();
details(placeId);
}
```

here is search() function .... placeID is global arraylist variable

```
public void search() {
String url ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?Location="+lat+","+longg+"&radius=5000&type=hospital&name=Hospital&key=AIzaSyA71lHTBWnb8uNvUI0N8ch8lhvla_0pM8";
Log.e("URL 1st : ", url);
final ArrayList<String> idd = new ArrayList<>();
Response.Listener<JSONObject> myListener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
String status = null;
try {
status = response.getString("status");
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
if (status != null && status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")) {
Log.e("Response Status: ", "search was successful but returned no results.This may occur if the search was passed a latlng in a remote location.");
Toast.makeText(NearByHospitals.this, "You are in remote location.\nNo Nearby Hospitals", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (status != null && status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT")) {
Log.e("Response Status: ", "indicates that you are over your quota.");
} else if (status != null && status.equals("REQUEST_DENIED")) {
Log.e("Response Status: ", "indicates that your request was denied, generally because of lack of an invalid key parameter.");
} else if (status != null && status.equals("INVALID_REQUEST")) {
Log.e("Response Status: ", "generally indicates that a required query parameter (location or radius) is missing.");
} else {
int sizeOfResponse = 0;
try {
sizeOfResponse = response.getJSONArray("results").length();
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfResponse; i++) {
try {
if (response.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(i).has("opening_hours") && response.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("opening_hours").getBoolean("open_now")) {
placeId.add(response.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(i).getString("place_id"));
Log.e("iddd", response.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(i).getString("place_id"));
locat.add(String.valueOf(response.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat")) + "," + String.valueOf(response.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng")));
}
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
}
};
Response.ErrorListener myErrorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
Toast.makeText(NearByHospitals.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
};
JsonObjectRequest myRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, null, myListener, myErrorListener);
Volley.newRequestQueue(NearByHospitals.this).add(myRequest);
}
```

I want to use placeId(global arraylist) in my details function for further details
here is my details() function

```
public void details(ArrayList<String>  strId) {

    for (int i = 0; i < strId.size(); i++) {
        try {
            String url2 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=" + strId.get(i) + "&key=AIzaSyA718lHTBWnb8uNvUI0N8ch8lhvla_0pM8";
            Log.e("URL2 ", url2);
            Response.Listener<JSONObject> myListener2 = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    String status = null;
                    try {
                        status = response.getString("status");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (status != null && status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")) {
                        Log.e("Response Status: ", "indicates that the reference was valid but no longer refers to a valid result. This may occur if the establishment is no longer in business.");
                    } else if (status != null && status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT")) {
                        Log.e("Response Status: ", "indicates that you are over your quota.");
                    } else if (status != null && status.equals("REQUEST_DENIED")) {
                        Log.e("Response Status: ", "indicates that your request was denied, generally because of lack of an invalid key parameter.");
                    } else if (status != null && status.equals("INVALID_REQUEST")) {
                        Log.e("Response Status: ", "generally indicates that the query (reference) is missing.");
                    } else {
                        if (status != null && status.equals("OK")) {
                            try {
                                hosNames.add(response.getJSONObject("result").getString("name"));
                                phoneNumbers.add(response.getJSONObject("result").getString("international_phone_number"));

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            Response.ErrorListener myErrorListener2 = new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(NearByHospitals.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            };
            JsonObjectRequest myRequest2 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url2, null, myListener2, myErrorListener2);
            Volley.newRequestQueue(NearByHospitals.this).add(myRequest2);

        } catch (NullPointerException l) {
            l.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

BUT THE PROBLEM IS THE placeId is empty and its size is zero. I check this variable in debugging n everything is fine arraylist was modified there while debugging. I Don't Know Where's I'm wrong ???

Comment: I instantiated arraylists in onCreate() function and did not get any error .

Answer (score 0):

From below:

```
search();
details(placeId);
```

In the method search() You are modifying the placeId list on an asynchronous thread so when you run details(placeId), the placeId you are passing as argument doesn't is not guarantee to have the list modified.  You might want to call details(placeId) when you are done filling placeId within the volley response.

Comment: got it... Thanks ... I called details() in the end of search() and passed placeID as an argument.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Please accept answer if it help you.

Comment: I wanted to mark your suggestion as ans but my rep is too low and cant vote for ans :( Thanks again